# Check if user has access to Content database in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In my code I'm running under elevated privileges, to access other Web applications. But I get a security error when the web application user can't access the database (when ever I try to access a SPWeb object).

Is there a way to make sure (in code) that a user has access to the Content database of a web application before trying to access sites in a site collection on that web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't make sure of this in code. If you're having your web app pools running as different accounts then you need to impersonate the other web app pool accounts.